# Keras `multi_gpu_model` usage causes error `yolo_head` is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, yolo

I have a keras_yolo python implementation, and I am trying to get the learning to work across multiple GPUs, and the multi_gpu_mode option sounds like a good place to start.

However, my problem is that the same code works just fine in a single CPU/GPU setup but fails with NameError: name 'yolo_head' is not defined when running as a multi_gpu_mode model. The full stack:

`parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, cpu_relocation=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/multi_gpu_utils.py", line 200, in multi_gpu_model
    model = clone_model(model)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 251, in clone_model
    return _clone_functional_model(model, input_tensors=input_tensors)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 152, in _clone_functional_model
    layer(computed_tensors, **kwargs))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 457, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 687, in call
    return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
  File "/mnt/data/DeepLeague/YAD2K/yad2k/models/keras_yolo.py", line 199, in yolo_loss
    pred_xy, pred_wh, pred_confidence, pred_class_prob = yolo_head(`

Here is a link to the definition of `yolo_head`: https://github.com/farzaa/DeepLeague/blob/c87fcd89d9f9e81421609eb397bf95433270f0e2/YAD2K/yad2k/models/keras_yolo.py#L66

I've not yet dived into the `multi_gpu_model` code to understand how the copying worked under the hood and was hoping to avoid needing to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because custom imports in the lambda used in Keras must be imported explicitly within the function referring to it.

eg. in this case `yolo_head` must be 're-imported' at the function level of `yolo_loss' like this:

```
def yolo_loss(args, anchors, num_classes, rescore_confidence=False, print_loss=False):
    from yad2k.models.keras_yolo import yolo_head
```